# DataGridview repaints very slowly

Tags: .net, datagridview, delay, repaint, winapp

I'm using datagridview in windows application developed in C# VS2005 .net 2.0.

Datagridview is provided a list of business objects. It take annoying delay of 2-3 seconds before starting displaying the rows in datagridview in falling-curtain fashion. When I switch back to my application from any other window it start repaint process in the same falling-curtain fashion.
This is quite annoying. Plz someone help me sort this out!

Comment: Can you reduce the code to the minimum that repeats the problem and post it - or just post what you think are the relevant sections.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you are going back to the data source to repopulate the grid every time you repaint the grid.

Comment: How many rows did you stuff into that grid?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it works, but setting the DataGridView control to double-buffered works an absolute treat. Make sure the DoubleBuffered property on the host-form is false also.

After doing this, my grid control went from redrawing so slowly (regardless of data-volume)  that you could almost count the cells as they went in, - to redrawing as quick as any other control.

The DoubleBuffered property is protected on the DataGridView, so you will need to create a derived class and set the property there, eg:

```
class DoubleBufferDataGrid : DataGridView
{
    public DoubleBufferDataGrid()
        : base()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```